# Monster movie where the creature removes its victims from history

Tags: story-identification, movie

The monster first attacks a couple that are parked in a construction site. There is an older guy who has been hunting this thing for years.

Every time the creature kills someone they are erased from history as if they never existed. This monster appears every 3-4 years.

The main couple rent every movie of this creature from a video store. The movies share the same name as the title of the one we watch. While watching the movie they figure out it is going to attack their friends party which it does. It is revealed to have the tentacles but also has sharp teeth.

The older guy kills it with dynamite after saying to the creature “you know what I love about thanksgiving? Leftovers”. The movie ends with a time jump of 3-4 years and the monster is back swimming in a lake.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where and when did you see this?  I assume it was live-action?

Comment: The *"Every time the creature kills someone they are erased from history as if they never existed."* idea was used more recently in a *Doctor Who* novel, [*Engines of War*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22401661-doctor-who). Though not very well IMO.

Comment: An episode of *Red Dwarf* has a similar premise, possibly “The Inquisitor” in series 5.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern, it was even in the main show, during Matt Smith era (it was featured in the first episode with him, and then was the monster-of-the-episode later).

Comment: @AntonSherwood I think it was indeed *The Inquisitor*, yes. Some similar shenanigans happened in *Timeslides* (series 3) as well.

Answer (score 29):

It's possible this is the 1999 made-for-TV movie [*Monster!*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0210180/).

The movie opens in a movie-within-the-movie with a young man and woman in a 1950s setting, driving a convertible through town to a theatre where they try to warn other people in town just as something starts to rip its way through from behind the screen.  The young man unloads a tommy gun at it, then throws a grenade into its mouth, killing it and saving the town.  The End.

The movie returns to present time, where M. Emmet Walsh plays an aging actor, Lloyd Reeves, who played the hero in a series of 6 movies like the above.  His grandson Travis arrives in town, which turns out to be where the movies were shot; the theatre featured above is still there, and the town is holding a festival to celebrate the movies.

Well, of course the monster is real, it comes back, and it's up to Lloyd and Travis to fight it off once again.

The movie does end with a shot of a tentacle in a lake, indicating that the monster either wasn't alone, or wasn't really killed.

[B-Movie Monsters](https://bmovie-monsters.fandom.com/wiki/Monster(Monster!_1999_Film)) has a short synopsis, in case I missed anything important.

[image: The toothy monster from Monster!]

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that indeed, the monster erases people from history, as per " The curse made people who witnessed the beast to forget about it and that the ones that The Monster killed ceased to exist." in that B-Move Monsters wiki entry.

Comment: If this is done even mildly well, or badly enough, it sounds quite entertaining.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the movie I was looking for. My quest is finally over

Comment: @MonsterMovieCollector:  If this is the answer to your question, you should mark the question as "resolved" by clicking on the green check-mark near the top left of this answer.